# How device drivers work like USB , CD, DVD

Tags: usb, drivers, compact-disc

I would like to know how device drivers work (on any platform, but would like to know the differences between drivers on Windows, Linux, and OSX). Specifically I'd like to know how devices are detected and used inside a computer.

I would also like to know which programming language device drivers are usually written in, and how I can write my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge question, outside of the scope of a forum post.

I would recommend reading Andrew Tanenbaum's books, *Modern Operating Systems*, and *Operating Systems: Design and Implementation* or some similar textbook on the subject. There are a few more, but he's the one I have read, *Modern Operating Systems* and it is excellent. I haven't read the second, yet, but am working on it :)

Also, for USB, the specifications are available online: http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/